# Datepicker Date is not changing on event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using material-UI datepicker which i followed the procedure but on event handler the date is not changing but the initial value is working fine which i give in `useState`. I want my datepicker to work smooth when i want to select my desire date. The example of Datepicker is also in the link

https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#date-time-pickers
https://codesandbox.io/s/z9k3z

```
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function AddCar() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  const addCar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
    setDate(new Date());
  };
  return (
    <div className="addCar">
      <div>
        <form className="addCar__form" onSubmit={addCar}>
          {/* Date */}
          <div className="addCar__mainForm row ">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 my-2">
              <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                  disableToolbar
                  variant="inline"
                  format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                  margin="normal"
                  label="Select Date"
                  value={date}
                  onChange={(e) => setDate(date)}
                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    "aria-label": "change date",
                  }}
                />
              </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
            ADD CAR
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddCar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep setting the same date from state.

```js
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
// ...
onChange={(e) => setDate(date)}
```

It should be:

```js
onChange={(e) => setDate(e)}
```

The first parameter in **DatePicker**'s *onChange* callback is the new date you've just input.

Answer (score 1):

change this line
`onChange={(e) => setDate(date)}`
to

`onChange={setDate}`

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-siueb?file=/addCar.js:939-957

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value like

```
onChange={(e) => setDate(e)}
```

Also, You don't need to set the state like this:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
```